# WPF: Selectable usercontrol - How?

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m new to C# and WPF and have a problem I hope you can help with.

I have a WPF application with a stackpanel to which I add usercontrols by code to display the information stored in an instance of a class. The user can create instances, and musty be able to edit and delete instances of the class by selecting the usercontrol. The usercontrol contains a canvas for making a simple sketch as part of the information stored in the instance.

My problem is: How do I make the usercontrol selectable, so that the user can select an instance for editing or deleting, and so that I can address the canvas by code in a particular instance?

I hope you can help me.

/Morny

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Put the UserControl in the ItemTemplate of a ListBox. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).